# What is actual DC battery cell resistance

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

Lithium ion battery manufacturers show AC impedance in datasheets of their batteries. I am interested in DC resistance, so I could calculate heat loss on my cell. Why do they tell AC 1khz resistance, if batteries are mostly used in constant DC loads? Should I calculate it by myself somehow? I want to find out how much power is used for heat instead of actual useful power. Some articles say that DC resistance is about 4 times larger than AC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do they tell AC 1khz resistance

Because that is the impedance of the battery **for small variations of the load current**. Suppose you have a device which consumes 100 mA **on average**. I say on average because it actually doesn't consume a constant current. It consumes 90 mA or 110 mA and switches between these values at 1 kHz so 0.5 ms 90 mA then 0.5 ms 110 mA then again 0.5 ms 90 mA etc... Then the AC component (ripple) of that current is 10 mAp (10 mA peak = 20 mA Peak-Peak if you prefer).

Suppose the battery has an AC resistance of 10 ohms then that would mean that the AC current consumption of your device would result in a 10 mAp * 1 Ohms = 10 mVp **ripple** on the battery voltage.

The DC resistance relates to how much the battery voltage drops due to the load current. Suppose I do not connect a load and the battery measures 4.0 V. Then I connect my load. For simplicity this load should draw a **constant** current. Suppose I load the battery with a constant 100 mA. If the DC resistance of the battery was 5 Ohms then the battery voltage would drop by: 100 mA * 5 = 500 mV. So I would the battery voltage, under load, would be 4.0 V - 500 mA = 3.5 V.

In this case the power dissipated in the battery is 500 mV * 100 mA = 50 mW.

Answer (score 2):

With the confounding effects of polarisation and the run down of the battery, it's not possible to define good repeatable conditions under which to define or measure the DC resistance.

1 kHz is chosen as being fast enough to eliminate these two contributions to the change in terminal voltage with current, aka cell resistance.

Perhaps you'd like to have a crack at your own defintion of a DC resistance? Calorimetry (measurement of heat produced by the flowing current) sounds fine until you try to do it accurately on a real battery.